# How to find all words appearing between parenthesis?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file containing some words in parenthesis. I'd like to compile a list of all of the unique words appearing there, e.g.:

```
This is some (text).
This (text) has some (words) in parenthesis.
Sometimes, there are numbers, such as (123) in parenthesis too.
```

This would be the resulting list:

```
text
words
123
```

How can I list all of the items appearing between parenthesis?

Comment: I am interested in ignoring case of the matched words, also would like to show the line count of where the word appeared, like so... text: 1 2     words: 2   123: 3.  I have used grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+' file.txt | sort -fu option but unable to get the line counts. If I add the -n option to grep then sorting dpesn't work quite well.                                                            Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

`awk -F "[()]" '{ for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) print $i }' file.txt`

prints:

```
text
text
words
123
```

You can use an array to print the unique values:

`awk -F "[()]" '{ for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) array[$1]=$i; print array[$1] }' file.txt`

prints:

```
text
words
123
```

HTH

Comment: Like this it's elegant. Unbalanced parenthesis will fail, however, since its really just using the parenthesis as delimiters.

'"1) See if (this)(word) is caught"'

Prints 'See if'

Answer (score 6):

With GNU grep, you can use a perl-compatible regex with look-around assertions to exclude the parens:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\().*?(?=\))' file.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: +1 I knew this could be done with a nice grep. Added the sort and uniq pipes for consistency

Answer (score 3):

`grep -oE '\([[:alnum:]]*?\)' | sed 's/[()]//g' | sort | uniq`

- `-o` Only prints the matching text
- `-E` means use extended regular expressions
- `\(` means match a literal paren
- `[[:alnum:]]` is the POSIX character class for letters and numbers.

That `sed` script should strip out the parens. This is tested against GNU grep, but BSD sed so be wary.

Comment: I needed to attach the global `g` flag to the end of my sed command, but otherwise this worked.

Comment: That's what i get for typing and not copying!

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce your list:

```
cat file.txt | sed  's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/'
```

To compile a list of unique words, you need to process the list further:

```
cat file.txt | sed  's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: This won't work on a sentence that contains more than one `(word)`. sed will only find one match.

Comment: can you correct this, as this wont work on sentences as suggested by @chrisaycock

Comment: @VenkatMadhav The accepted answer from steve works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 sed -e 's/\(/\n\(/g' -e 's/\)/\n/g' filename|awk -F'(' '{print $2}'|sort -u
```

Explaination:

The 1st sed statement places the words in parenthesis in new line and the second sed replaces the character ')' with new line. So after running the below statement

```
sed -e 's/\(/\n\(/g' -e 's/\)/\n/g' filename
```

the output would look like this

```
This is some 
(text
.This 
(text
has some 
(words
 in parenthesis.
Sometimes, there are numbers, such as 
(123
 in parenthesis too.
```

Now piping this output to below awk statement which prints the second word between the filter character '('

```
awk -F'(' '{print $2}'
```

the output now will be

```
text
text
words
123
```

the above output is piped to sort -u command to give unique words from the above output.
Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: @AK_ edited my answer with explanation. Hope that helps and up-vote the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: @AK_. Thank you. Will keep in mind to briefly explain my answer in future posts to make life easier for those who may be needing it.