# How to find all of the words appearing between `\word{}` in BASH?

Tags: bash

I have a file like this:

```
This \word{is} some text.
This is some \word{more text}.
\word{This} is \word{yet} some more \word{text}.
```

I need to create a list of all of the text that appears between `\word{` and the matching closing brace, `}`, e.g.:

```
is
more text
This
yet
text
```

- The opening and closing braces always appear on the same line, never across multiple lines.
- Other braces are present in the document, but none appear inside `\word{}`.

How can I print a list of all of the text appearing in `\word{}`?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you considered? Giving us context of what solutions you've attempted will usually help us figure out what sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all words appearing between parenthesis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661646/how-to-find-all-words-appearing-between-parenthesis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

grep with PCRE capabilities will do the job:

```
grep -Po "(?<=\\word{)[^}]*(?=})" file
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/uzEzBF

Comment: @Village: I have tried above grep command with your input `{ This \word{is} some text }` and got `is` back. What output did you expect?

Comment: +1 for the simplest solution of all. Though not sure if we need postive lookahead too. This should suffice `"(?<=\\word{)[^}]+"` but I'm no expert on `regexes` :)

Comment: @JS웃: Thanks and agreed that `grep -Po "(?<=\\word{)[^}]*" file` should be sufficient.

Comment: I would be concerned that `\word{is {this} ok?}` would return `is {this`.  If @Village isn't going to have to deal with nested brackets that's fine, but it's still a possible issue.  What about the recursive regex `(?<=\\word{)([^{}]*|(?1)*(?:{(?1)}?)*(?1)*)(?=})`?  By replacing the `[^}]` with a definition of an allowed capture group: "ok content is blank, characters other than '{}', or ok content, followed by {ok content}, followed by ok content", I think we cover everything.

Comment: @zebediah49: If nested brackets is a requirement I will be happy to put more complex regex in my answer.

Comment: @Village: Did you find anything wrong with this answer? Pls also note that question was tagged as BASH hence only BASH provided tools/utilities were suggested as a solution.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you're handling a TeX file... so why not use TeX to do this directly? Then you'll be sure there won't be any problems and side effects, e.g.,

```tex
\word {there's a space between \verb=\word= and the curly bracket}
```

this would still work! It will still work for multi-line stuff:

```tex
\word{this is
    a multiline stuff \emph{and you can even add more groupings in it,}
    it'll still work fine!}
```

In your (La)TeX preamble, just add:

```tex
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=output.txt

\def\word#1{\immediate\write\file{#1}}
```

or use `\newcommand` if you're using LaTeX and not plainTeX.

You can also put the `\immediate\write\file{#1}` inside your `\word` definition macro. If you don't have access to the `\word` macro (e.g., it's in a class or style file) you can:

```tex
\let\oldword\word
\def\word#1{\immediate\write\file{#1}\oldword{#1}}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

A pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution without calling any external utilities:

```
while read -r x; do
  while [[ $x =~ \\word{([^}]+)} ]]; do
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    x=${x#*$BASH_REMATCH}
  done
done <infile
```

Input file:

```
$ cat infile
This \word{is} some text.
{This \word{is}}some text.
This is some \word{more text}.
\word{This} is \word{yet} some more \word{text}.
```

Output:

```
is
is
more text
This
yet
text
```

The trick is the `-r` option set in `read` [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) built-in function. This will not treat `\` as an escape character in the line read. Then it loops while the `\word{...}` pattern is found in the string. Then the internal matched string is printed and the input sting chomped.

For small files (1-2 MB) I would use this version as it uses very minimal resources. But for large files I suggest to use [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s [perl-regex](/questions/tagged/perl-regex)-[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509911/how-to-find-all-of-the-words-appearing-between-word-in-bash/17591229#17509954) as it reads the file much more efficiently!

Answer (score 3):

Since not all versions of grep have PCRE, here is a solution using only extended regex.

`grep -Eo "\\word{.+}" file_name | sed -e "s/\\word{//" -e "s/}//"`

Comment: This code gets confused if other `{` or `}` are present in the lines.

Comment: How so? What output did you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat testfile
This \word{is} some text.
This is some \word{more text}.
\word{This} is \word{yet} some more \word{text}.

$ awk '$0 ~ /\\word{[^}]*}/ { nelts = split($0, arr, /\\word{/); for (i=1; i <= nelts; i++) if (arr[i] ~ /^[^}]*}/) print substr(arr[i], 1, index(arr[i], "}") - 1); }' testfile
is
more text
This
yet
text
```

If there happened to be `\word{\word{STRING}}`, STRING would get printed. In other words, it works recursively. Sorry if that isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing grep and sed:

```
egrep -o '\\word\{[^\{\}]+\}' | sed 's/\\word{//;s/}//'
```

For fun, I have also made up a pure bash version:

```
while read -r l
do
    n=${#l}
    ll="${l#*\\word{}"
    while [ $n -ne ${#ll} ]
    do
        echo "${ll%%\}*}"
        n=${#ll}
        ll="${ll#*\\word{}"
    done
done
```

Not very clean, but it works on your example

Comment: I assume that your `bash` solution will not work. The `read` built-in will treat ` \ ` as an escape character, so `l` will not contain it. Use `read -r` instead!

Comment: @TrueY: I test my little script under Cygwin and it works fine like this.
But you arre right so I edit my answer. thanks

Comment: Hmmm... I also tried my answer on `cygwin` and I found the `-r` switch because it did not work for me.

Comment: @TrueY : indeed. I think the `=~` interprets backslashes. The command `echo $x` placed before your inner while loop outputs the original line with backslashes. But without -r, it's not working. With mine it's ok as I am not using `=~`.

Comment: If I use `while read x; do echo "$x"; done <infile` under `cygwin` I get the lines without `\ `, like `This word{is} some text.` (no `\ `).

Comment: @TrueY: oops I mixed two lines on my terminal; you are right. `read -r` is needed. I have to edit again my answer: as I don't see that backslashes are lost, I am searching for `word{` as I don't espace the backslash. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -nr ':b;s/(\\word\{[^}]+\})/\1\n/;s/.*\\word\{([^}]+)\}\n/\1\n/;T;P;D;tb' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
This \word{is} some text.
This is some \word{more text}.
\word{This} is \word{yet} some more \word{text}.
{\word{This} is \word{yet} {some} more \word{text}.}

$ sed -nr ':b;s/(\\word\{[^}]+\})/\1\n/;s/.*\\word\{([^}]+)\}\n/\1\n/;T;P;D;tb' file
is
more text
This
yet
text
This
yet
text
```

Answer (score 1):

awk was invented to do text processing:

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*\\word{/,"")' RS='}' file
is
more text
This
yet
text
is

$ cat file
This \word{is} some text.
This is some \word{more text}.
\word{This} is \word{yet} some more \word{text}.
{ This \word{is} some text }
```

Answer (score 1):

perl can helps too:

```
perl -nlE 'say "$_" for (m/\\word\{(.*?)\}/g);'  < tex.txt
```

for this input:

```
This{ \word{is}} some text.
This is some \word{more text}.
This is {some \word{aaa text}} This is {some \word{bbb text} This is some \word{ccc text}} This is some {\word{ddd text}}
{\word{This} is \word{yet} some more \word{text}.}
```

prints:

```
is
more text
aaa text
bbb text
ccc text
ddd text
This
yet
text
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*\\word{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/g' input.txt
```

The expression above deletes everything except what's inside the brackets. If it turns out in the future that you need to match across multiple lines, `awk` might be easier:

```
awk -F "\\word{" 'BEGIN { RS = "}" } { print $2 }' input.txt
```

This sets `\word{` as the field-separator and `}` as the record-separator, implying that `$2` refers to what's inside the brackets.