# How to search for all words between A and Z, which are further enclosed with { and } in BASH?

Tags: bash, grep

I need to output all of the text appearing between A and Z, but only those where A and Z are further found somewhere within `{` and `}`.

Here is a sample file:

```
Once upon a AtimeZ, a mouse climbed up a tree.
Once at {the }top of AaZ {treeA, Zhe AfoundZ an apple.}
"Oh, this {is a Anice Zapple,"A saidZ the} AmouseZ.
The mouse ate {the AappleZ} happily.
```

The output would look like this:

```
, 
found
nice 
 said
apple
```

- The file contains no nested `{` or `}`'s.
- The `{` and `}`'s are never split across multiple lines.
- The `{` and `}`'s never appear between the "A" and "Z".

I've modified some code from [How to find all of the words appearing between `\word{}` in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509911/how-to-find-all-of-the-words-appearing-between-word-in-bash), like this:

```
grep -Po "(?<=\{.*A)[^Z.*\}]*(?=Z.*\})" found.csv1 > found.csv2
```

This prints this error:

```
grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length
```

How can I output a list of all of the text that is found between A and Z, with each matched text printed to a new line, but only if the text between A and Z are further found somewhere with `{` and `}` on the same line?

Answer (score 3):

It can be more clear to use two `grep` commands:

```
grep -Po '(?<={)[^}]*' file | grep -Po '(?<=A)[^Z]*'
```

#### Explanation

Firstly, get strings in between brackets:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<={)[^}]*' file
the 
treeA, Zhe AfoundZ an apple.
is a Anice Zapple,"A saidZ the
the AappleZ
```

Then pipe to get text in between A-Z:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<={)[^}]*' a | grep -Po '(?<=A)[^Z]*'
, 
found
nice 
 said
apple
```

Answer (score 3):

This grep can do that in single regex:

```
grep -Po 'A\K[^Z]*(?=Z)(?=[^{}]*\})' file
, 
found
nice 
 said
apple
```

OR else this will also work with lookbehind:

```
grep -Po '(?<=A)[^Z]*(?=Z)(?=[^{}]*\})' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit inefficient, but should work:

```
grep -Po '{[^}]*A[^}]*Z.*}' found.csv1  | grep -oP '(?<=A).*?(?=Z)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Haha that involved lots of tinkering for me but I like this problem see if this works for you.

It looks repetitive( sed | grep | cut ) because it gets job done in two steps:

-isolate just text between {}

-isolate just text between AZ

```
cat text | sed 's/{/\n/g' | grep "}" | cut -d "}" -f 1 | sed 's/A/\n/g' | grep "Z" | cut -d "Z" -f 1
```